# How to get list of ALL apps (including System Apps)?

Tags: android, android-package-managers, installed-applications

I am doing the following to get the list of apps and I am only getting apps that were installed but not ALL apps, including system apps.

I have tried the following:

```
    packageList1 = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

and this:

```
    packageList1 = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

For both cases, I am getting the same list of apps that I have installed on the phone.

Comment: Are you sure that the list does not contain system apps? Because it should, most likely you are interpreting the data you get wrong. Loop through all the `ApplicationInfos` and the ones that have the flag `FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP` or `FLAG_SYSTEM` are system apps.

Comment: You are right, i was misunderstanding part of my code (i do some post processing after getting the list)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all apps installed on android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393607/how-to-get-all-apps-installed-on-android-phone)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are already getting a list of all installed applications including the system apps by calling this:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

Those with the flags:

- `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP`
- `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM`

are system apps. You can check for the flags like this:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
    if((app.flags & (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP | ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)) > 0) {
        // It is a system app
    } else {
        // It is installed by the user
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i get all packages in android oreo , not woking for android 8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
    if((app.flags & (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP | ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)) > 0) {
        // It is a system app
    } else {
        // It is installed by the user
    }
}
```