# Finding all the installed Apps on Android including Google Mobile Service Apps

Tags: android, android-package-managers, installed-applications

This question has been asked before:
[How to get list of ALL apps (including System Apps)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599550/how-to-get-list-of-all-apps-including-system-apps)

However, when I called `getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0)`, it did not return all the apps. For example, the following apps were not found by this call: `com.google.android.music, com.google.android.youtube, com.google.earth, com.google.android.gm`.

Is it because they are part of Google Mobile Service?

Comment: Which device are you working on ?

Comment: It is Nexus 5, Android 5.0.2.

Comment: Try including the flag for metadata, or try calling `getInstalledApplications()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledAppInfos(Context context) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    return packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
}
```

Test:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getInstalledAppInfos(this);
for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
         Log.d(TAG, "App( " + i + ") " + apps.get(i).packageName);
}
```